# In Log Shipping configuration with SQL2005, Primary server's backup job not being added

Tags: sql-server-2005, failover

I'm creating a log shipping configuration between two sql server 2005 instances.  I'm shipping the logs of a single database and I'm not using a Monitor service (for the time being).  When I run the SQL Server Log Shipping Wizard on the database, the script executes as it should and claims there are no errors.  But when it's complete, the secondary server has the correct list of Jobs (copy/restore) but the primary server, I think, should have a "backup" job.  It doesn't.

So it's either failing silently or I'm misunderstanding how log shipping works.  Does anyone know a) if there should be a job added to the primary server and b) if there is supposed to be a job, what some of the likely causes for it not being added might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the silent failure was being caused by the fact that the secondary server was actually a virtual machine that was a clone of the primary server.  Even though I had changed both the computer name and the sql server name.  I'm guessing there's something else that identifies the instance that was not changed and this was causing the failure.  That's just a guess, though.